# Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Tags: php, sql-server, formularios, login, validación

Tengo un problema, no puedo conectar la base de datos a un archivo php, lo necesito para una validacion de datos en un formulario login. Aqui les muestro mi codigo PHP:

```
<?php 

$Administrador = $_POST['AdminName'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
if (isset($_POST['btnAdmin'])) {    

    $dsn = "sqlsrv:server=AFTIC004;database=UneteAlPArche_BD";
    $Admin = "codestack";
    $Password = "jrdLpWad5ik3rFWatjLQ"; 
    try{
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $Admin, $Password);
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Fallo la conexión <br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM sisAdministrador WHERE IdAdmin = 1, Nombre = 'Administrador' AND Password = '$contrasena' AND IdRol = 3";
    $params = array(1, "some data");
    $resultado= sqlsrv_query($conn, $consulta, $params);

    if ($resultado == false) {
        echo "Consulta erronea";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        return false;
    }else{
        echo "Consulta exitosa";
        header("location: VentanaReportesAdminIngresado.html");
    }
}
?>
```

Si ven mi error en alguna parte haganmelo saber, les aclaro una cosa, soy aun un novato en esto, asi que espero entienda mi falta de conocimiento en el tema. Espero su respuesta pronto

Comment: El error viene porque estás pasando a sqlsrv_query() como primer parámetro la variable $conn, que es un objeto, pero esa función espera un recurso. Si vas a usar las funciones sqlsrv, establece la conexión con sqlsrv_connect(), no con PDO.

Answer (score -1):

Al parecer el problema esta en los parámetros que pasas ya que no son aplicados en tu consulta.

intenta cambiar tu arreglo de parámetros de la siguiente manera es importante el orden de los parámetros.

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM sisAdministrador WHERE IdAdmin = ?, Nombre = ? AND Password = ? AND IdRol = ?";
$params = array(1, $Administrador,$contrasena,3);
```

puedes no pasar los parámetros si en tu consulta ya los definiste

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM sisAdministrador WHERE IdAdmin = 1, Nombre = '$Administrador' AND Password = '$contrasena' AND IdRol = 3";
    $resultado= sqlsrv_query($conn, $consulta);
```

Comment: Una cosa, ¿los signos de pregunta son opcionales o son obligatorios para que funcione?

Comment: son obligatorios, puedes dejar la consulta como lo tienes pero no le pases $params

Comment: No te entiendo cuando dices "no le pases $params. Ya lo tengo como esta en la ilustracion que dejaste, pero el error persiste. Sale este error: Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ventana reportes\validar.php on line 18
Consulta erronea. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )

Comment: El problema es con $conn.